# Visual illustrations of circle packing theorem?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, computational-geometry, packing-problem, planar-graphs

[Circle packing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem) states:

*For every connected simple planar graph G there is a circle packing in the plane whose intersection graph is (isomorphic to) G.*

Paper [Collins, Stephenson: A circle packing algorithm](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CHAQFjAG&url=http://www.researchgate.net/publication/222403200_A_circle_packing_algorithm/file/50463521dfbd4a3c58.pdf&ei=aTRxU5_GD8ec0QW6x4DoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEEp_EJyMyfmDTikDCOnWdlNAm-ig&sig2=pU0zLPnoVh_U1GP868ln2A&bvm=bv.66330100,d.d2k&cad=rja) describes an algorithm for obtaining circle pack corresponding to a given planar graph.

However, I tried searching internet for images of resulting circle packs, and I could hardly find just a few. Those that I found had some unusual beauty in them. I suspect whole beauty of such circle packs is still not discovered.

I would like to know if somebody tried to generate circle packs corresponding to some known classes of planar graphs, like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

or similar?

---

Some rare visual examples that I found on internet.:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have computed circle packings in various special cases taking advantage of symmetry.
However, I have not implemented circle packing in full generality.

[image]

The US graph is featured in a review of [Hyperbolic Geometry](http://www.math.brown.edu/~rkenyon/papers/cannon.pdf) by Cannon, Floyed, Kenyon and Parry.  Square tilings are another geometric object associated with planar graphs.

[image]

---

It's hard to find good implementations of circle packing.  Even we had some, the software is slowly going out of date.  At least, a theory is pinned down in some papers:

- [The convergence of circle packings to the Riemann mapping](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214441375) that any graph has circle packings leads to a proof of the Riemann Mapping theorem
- [On the convergence of circle packings to the Riemann Map](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/He96.pdf)
- [Approximation of Conformal Structures via Circle Packing](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Stephenson97.pdf)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem) has many interesting references as well.

Comment: John, can you perhaps post here some of circle packings that you produced manually?

Comment: @VividD The first one is mine.  It is related to the [Farey Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Answer (score 4):

If you read the very last item in the paper that you linked, you will see that the authors of that paper give a [link to software that computes circle packings](http://www.math.utk.edu/~kens/).